# Spring Data JPA Repository findAllInList including nulls

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a Spring JPA repository:

```
@Repository
interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {

  List<User> findByTypeIn(List<String> types);
}
```

And I want to include `User` entities which have `type is null` into the results of this method. I tried something like `findByTypeInOrTypeIsNotNull` or `findByTypeIsNullOrIn and it didn't work. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you try just including `null` as a value in the list?

Comment: @Jorn I tried but it didn't count that null value in the list in my case.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to find users where type is null, yet your method name is findByTypeInOrTypeIs**Not**Null.